# Additional parameters in def__init__ for Optuna Trial

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, optuna

```
class ConvolutionalNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features):
        super().__init__()
        self.in_features = in_features
        # this computes num features outputted from the two conv layers
        c1 = int(((self.in_features - 2)) / 64)  # this is to account for the loss due to conversion to int type
        c2 = int((c1-2)/64)
        self.n_conv = int(c2*16)
        #self.n_conv = int((( ( (self.in_features - 2)/4 ) - 2 )/4 ) * 16) 
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(1, 16, 3, 1)
        self.conv1_bn = nn.BatchNorm1d(16)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(16, 16, 3, 1)
        self.conv2_bn = nn.BatchNorm1d(16)
        self.dp = nn.Dropout(trial.suggest_uniform('dropout_rate',0,1.0))
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(self.n_conv, 2)
```

As you can see, `def __init__` already has `self` and `in_features` as the variable. I am thinking of adding another variable `trial` (which is part of the Optuna package) to accommodate

```
    self.dp = nn.Dropout(trial.suggest_uniform('dropout_rate',0,1.0))
```

in the above codes. Please advise how, most only sources only has `def __init__ (self, trial)`, which is pretty straightforward, but for my case I have 3 variables to be passed in the objective.

Comment: Hey, Id like to help but I dont understand the question at all. Maybe you can rephrase it?

Comment: Adding one more keyword argument to `__init__` should be trivial, but I'm guessing you are trying to ask either how to make it optional, or how to actually use it inside the `__init__` function. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: in this case , there are 3 variables in this objective  ( self , in_features , trial) , if I am to add trial into __init__ and run the code , it would say trial not defined.   trial.suggest is part of the command in the Optuna package , which I have imported earlier on with "import Optuna". The purpose is to tune the parameters , run the model to find out what is the best hyper parameters with the highest accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class ConvolutionalNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, trial, in_features):
        # code for initialization
        ..........

def objective(trial):
    # code to create in_features
    in_features = ......
    #generate the model
    model = ConvolutionalNetwork(trial, in_features)
    ..................
    # code to run the CNN and calculate the accuracy.
    return accuracy

# Create study and optimise the objective function.
study = optuna.create_study()
study.optimize(objective, n_trails=100, timeout=600)
```